# echo MySQL data into html form with radio buttons with other text field

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

In my web form, users can submit product data into a MySQL database. The supplier field gives our users the choice between 3 radio buttons (our most frequently used suppliers being Sigma-Aldrich, VWR and Filter-Service), or a 4th 'other' radio button with a text field, where they can specify the 'other' supplier. This is done using the following code:

php side:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$q2_productname = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['q2_productname']);
$q3_supplier = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['q3_supplier']);
if ($q3_supplier =='other'){
  $q3_supplier = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['q3_supplier_other']);
}
```

and the form on the html side:

```
<fieldset>
<div>
<label for="q2"><font color="red">*</font> Full product name:</label><br />
<input id="q2" type="text" style="width:400px" name="q2_productname" required="true" tabindex="2">
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<div>
<label for="q3"><font color="red">*</font> Supplier:</label><br />
<input id="q3" type="radio" name="q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="Sigma-Aldrich" onchange="disableTxt()" checked="checked" />Sigma-Aldrich &nbsp;
<input id="q3" type="radio" name="q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="VWR" onchange="disableTxt()" />VWR &nbsp;
<input id="q3" type="radio" name="q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="Filter-Service" onchange="disableTxt()" />Filter-Service &nbsp;
<input id="q3" type="radio" name="q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="other" onchange="enableTxt()" />Other:
<input id="other" type="text" name="q3_supplier_other" required="true" tabindex="3" disabled="disabled" />
<script>
function disableTxt() {
    document.getElementById("other").disabled = true;
}
function enableTxt() {
    document.getElementById("other").disabled = false;
}
</script>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Now, I also have an edit page, where users can edit and update an entry.
For the normal text fields I've managed to echo the value into the text fields. **For the supplier I'd like to echo the value into the same layout as the webform (i.e. check the corresponding radio button and if it's 'other' then check the 'other' radio button and fill in the 'other' text field)**, but this seems to be rather difficult.

I'm trying

```
<input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="other" onchange="enableTxt()" <?php if (isset($q3_supplier) && $q3_supplier!="Sigma-Aldrich" OR "VWR" OR "Filter-Service") echo "checked";?> />Other:
```

to get the other radio button checked in case it's different to one of the 3 frequently used suppliers, and then I also put at the text field

```
<input id="other" type="text" name="ud_q3_supplier_other" required="true" tabindex="3" disabled="disabled" value="<?php if (isset($q3_supplier) && $q3_supplier!="Sigma-Aldrich" OR "VWR" OR "Filter-Service") echo $q3_supplier;?>" />
```

but the result is that the code always selects the other text field and fills in the value in the text field anyway, regardless of it being something different from Sigma-Aldrich, VWR or Filter-Service...

I'm thinking **the OR statements are not working correctly**, but my google and stackoverflow searches haven't resulted in solutions neither examples. Does anyone have tips to crack this issue?

The code for the editing form php side:

```
$sid = (int)$_GET['sid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE sid = '$sid'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $sid = $row['sid'];
        $q2_productname = $row['q2_productname'];
        $q3_supplier = $row['q3_supplier'];
    }
}
```

and html side:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<?=$sid;?>"><br>
<font color="red">*</font> Product name: <input id="q2" type="text" style="width:400px" name="ud_q2_productname" required="true" value="<?=$q2_productname?>" tabindex="2"><br>
<font color="red">*</font> Supplier: 
<input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="Sigma-Aldrich" onchange="disableTxt()" <?php if (isset($q3_supplier) && $q3_supplier=="Sigma-Aldrich") echo "checked";?> />Sigma-Aldrich &nbsp;
<input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="VWR" onchange="disableTxt()" <?php if (isset($q3_supplier) && $q3_supplier=="VWR") echo "checked";?> />VWR &nbsp;
<input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="Filter-Service" onchange="disableTxt()" <?php if (isset($q3_supplier) && $q3_supplier=="Filter-Service") echo "checked";?> />Filter-Service &nbsp;
<input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="other" onchange="enableTxt()" <?php if (isset($q3_supplier) && $q3_supplier!="Sigma-Aldrich" OR "VWR" OR "Filter-Service") echo "checked";?> />Other:
<input id="other" type="text" name="ud_q3_supplier_other" required="true" tabindex="3" disabled="disabled" value="<?php if (isset($q3_supplier) && $q3_supplier!="Sigma-Aldrich" OR "VWR" OR "Filter-Service") echo $q3_supplier;?>" /><br />
<script>
function disableTxt() {
    document.getElementById("other").disabled = true;
}
function enableTxt() {
    document.getElementById("other").disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/) and for your sake I hope this is not on the public internet. You need to ensure any and all user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you are at serious risk of an application compromise. Whenever possible use prepared statements and placeholders to ensure you're not exposed to errors of that sort. Are you using PDO or `mysqli` here?

Comment: 1. It is not on the public internet, it's only accessible to our group. 2. How exactly is it insecure? I'm a real beginner, but as far as I know I'm escaping all strings and using object oriented mysqli everywhere...

Comment: It's not on the public internet *today*, but you have no control over how this will be used in the future. This code is a serious liability already. Do it properly and you won't have problems. If you're using `mysqli`, use parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. This makes it much harder to make a serious mistake. You say you're escaping things everywhere but you're obviously missing the one where `$sid` is a `$_GET` parameter that is interpolated in your query. That's enough to kill your application.

Comment: you are true about the $_GET parameter. I updated it to `$sid = (int)$_GET['sid'];`. In our group, this code will always be private, it can only to be used by people inside our group having a validated account. It is however true that someone else could use parts of this code found here on SO for his own application. That I cannot control. I'll have to read about parameterized queries and `bind_param`, but is escaping everything still not enough then?

Comment: Escaping manually is error prone and will get you into trouble when you miss something. Use `bind_param` whenever possible and you'll avoid this. It's not hard to do, and makes your code a lot more readable as a bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it by adding php `if, elseif, else` tags. I put the `checked="checked"` with each if/elseif/else at the respective radio button.
It works like a charm :-).

I will provide the code here. **If someone else figures out a more elegant solution, please do tell!**

```
<form action="update_script.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<?=$sid;?>"><br>
<font color="red">*</font> Product name: <input id="q2" type="text" style="width:400px" name="ud_q2_productname" required="true" value="<?=$q2_productname?>" tabindex="2"><br>
<?php
if($q3_supplier == 'Sigma-Aldrich'){ ?>
<font color="red">*</font> Supplier: 
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="Sigma-Aldrich" onchange="disableTxt()" checked="checked" />Sigma-Aldrich &nbsp;
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="VWR" onchange="disableTxt()" />VWR &nbsp;
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="Filter-Service" onchange="disableTxt()" />Filter-Service &nbsp;
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="other" onchange="enableTxt()" />Other:
    <input id="other" type="text" name="ud_q3_supplier_other" required="true" tabindex="3" disabled="disabled" /><br />
    <script>
    function disableTxt() {
        document.getElementById("other").disabled = true;
    }
    function enableTxt() {
        document.getElementById("other").disabled = false;
    }
    </script>
<?php
} elseif($q3_supplier == 'VWR'){ ?>
<font color="red">*</font> Supplier: 
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="Sigma-Aldrich" onchange="disableTxt()" />Sigma-Aldrich &nbsp;
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="VWR" onchange="disableTxt()" checked="checked" />VWR &nbsp;
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="Filter-Service" onchange="disableTxt()" />Filter-Service &nbsp;
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="other" onchange="enableTxt()" />Other:
    <input id="other" type="text" name="ud_q3_supplier_other" required="true" tabindex="3" disabled="disabled" /><br />
    <script>
    function disableTxt() {
        document.getElementById("other").disabled = true;
    }
    function enableTxt() {
        document.getElementById("other").disabled = false;
    }
    </script>
<?php
} elseif($q3_supplier == 'Filter-Service'){ ?>
<font color="red">*</font> Supplier: 
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="Sigma-Aldrich" onchange="disableTxt()" />Sigma-Aldrich &nbsp;
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="VWR" onchange="disableTxt()" />VWR &nbsp;
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="Filter-Service" onchange="disableTxt()" checked="checked" />Filter-Service &nbsp;
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="other" onchange="enableTxt()" />Other:
    <input id="other" type="text" name="ud_q3_supplier_other" required="true" tabindex="3" disabled="disabled" /><br />
    <script>
    function disableTxt() {
        document.getElementById("other").disabled = true;
    }
    function enableTxt() {
        document.getElementById("other").disabled = false;
    }
    </script>
<?php
} else { ?>
<font color="red">*</font> Supplier: 
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="Sigma-Aldrich" onchange="disableTxt()" />Sigma-Aldrich &nbsp;
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="VWR" onchange="disableTxt()" />VWR &nbsp;
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="Filter-Service" onchange="disableTxt()" />Filter-Service &nbsp;
    <input id="q3" type="radio" name="ud_q3_supplier" required="true" tabindex="3" value="other" onchange="enableTxt()" checked="checked"/>Other:
    <input id="other" type="text" name="ud_q3_supplier_other" required="true" tabindex="3" enabled="enabled" value="<?php echo $q3_supplier;?>" /><br />
    <script>
    function disableTxt() {
        document.getElementById("other").disabled = true;
    }
    function enableTxt() {
        document.getElementById("other").disabled = false;
    }
    </script>
<?php
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your if statement when printing the radio buttons is wrong here.

Non-empty strings become `true` in boolean. So `$q3_supplier!="Sigma-Aldrich" OR "VWR" OR "Filter-Service"` validates as `true` anyway.

Your clause should be something like: `$q3_supplier!="Sigma-Aldrich" OR $q3_supplier!="VWR" OR $q3_supplier!="Filter-Service"`

See [PHP type comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: Tried this but with the same result. anyway, thanks for the answer. I also tried putting the OR clause in between brackets like this, but also without success. `if (isset($q3_supplier) && ($q3_supplier!="Sigma-Aldrich" OR $q3_supplier!="VWR" OR $q3_supplier!="Filter-Service"))`